# Easy question about coordinate rings

Tags: algebraic-curves

Let $C=V(x^2+y^2-1)$ be an affine algebraic curve. In an online course the professor said $\varphi=\frac{x-1}{y}\in A(C)$, but he didn't explain why.

I would like to know  how he gets this function  and why it's in the coordinate ring of the curve $C$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not true. The function blows up at $(-1, 0)$.

Comment: @ZhenLin It's regular at the point $(1,0)$, I think the professor meant at this point.

Comment: Functions in the coordinate ring are regular _everywhere_, however.